# Can't use GraphQL in the AEM

Tags: graphql, aem

I added GraphQL  to the bundle in the AEM and it caused bundle start failed.

1. I have a bundle project and it works fine in the AEM.  Bundle start command : mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle

> ```
>     <profile>  
>         <id>autoInstallBundle</id>  
>         <activation>  
>             <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>  
>         </activation>  
>         <build>  
>             <pluginManagement>  
>                 <plugins>  
>                     <plugin>  
>                         <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>  
>                         <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>  
>                         <executions>  
>                             <execution>  
>                                 <id>install-bundle</id>  
>                                 <goals>  
>                                     <goal>install</goal>  
>                                 </goals>  
>                             </execution>  
>                         </executions>  
>                     </plugin>  
>                 </plugins>  
>             </pluginManagement>  
>         </build>  
>     </profile>
> ```

2. I add below config to the pom.xml then reinstall bundle and bundle still work fine.

> ```
> <dependency>  
> <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>  
> <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>  
> <version>3.0.0</version>  
> </dependency>
> ```

3. I added two demo classes to my project and reinstall bundle. Bundle start failed. GraphQL_SImple.java and User.java can be found in the https://github.com/zhaiqianfeng/GraphQL-Demo/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/zqf/get_start/GraphQL_Simple.java
4. Error message is :

> 12.07.2018 14:55:17.223 *ERROR* [qtp1398311933-54244] org.apache.felix.http.jetty %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve
>   com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27): missing requirement
>   [com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=graphql) Unresolved requirements:
>   [[com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=graphql)])   org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
>   Unable to resolve com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27):
>   missing requirement [com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27)]
>   osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=graphql) Unresolved
>   requirements: [[com.mb.graphql.mb-graphql.core [528](R 528.27)]
>   osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=graphql)]   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4112)
>   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)   at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:364)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)   at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:563)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager$3.run(OsgiManager.java:465)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:461)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
>   at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:295)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>   at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:128)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Is anyone face same issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find a way to resolve it. add below config to the maven-bundle-plugin.

> ```
> <Export-Package>graphql.*</Export-Package>
> ```